# Trying to create File from URI fails Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, file, uri, activityresultcontracts

I am trying to create a File using the URI from ActivityResultContracts like this:

```
val galleryLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->

            val myFile = uri?.toFile()
```

The file is a jpeg image. I have got this error: `Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000000001`

Comment: Use fileutils to parse the uri and get the file's absolute path and then create a file object.

Comment: This is not a `file://` URI, so you can't get a `File` from it directly. I believe these `content://` URIs are meant to be used with Android's content providers, but I haven't worked on Android for quite some time. You should check this doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics

Comment: Could you give me an example Rahat?